# Woocommerce doesn't work, but all shortcodes there are

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Installed woocommerce version 4.0.1
Version wordpress 5.4

So i have simple index.php and other required php file like functions.php header.php and footer.php. That's all. And in my header menu I inserted woocommerce pages like cart shop and etc.
All pages hav required shortcodes, so I checked links url in wp. But when I click on shop link - url changes on shop page, but nothing changes in output. So I working index.php template and that's all. When I go to the shop page from wp dashboard, I have same results: cnanged url, but template index.php.
I tried add new pages with shortcode, but the same. What's wrong? And I have multisite on. Maybe there is some tools for checking problems? In woocommerse status I have just some errors.... look at image below. Thanx! 
[image]

Comment: Did you create a child theme? Did you not include the `style.css` for your child theme if you are using one?

Comment: What do you mean? Standart style.css for my theme I've already included, without this I cant activate theme wp, isn't it?

Comment: Correct. You need a style.css for your child theme. The reason I ask is in your screenshot, you have errors in your Theme section

Comment: it doesnt work(